# iphone app store phone contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, storage, contacts

We are developing an application in iOS (iPhone App) that is storing phone contacts in our server. We are planning to store phone number and email address of the contacts on the server(We have restful apis for storing the contact information). Should this lead to rejection of the app?

We have checked the various guidelines and couldn't not find any relevant information, but I remember I read somewhere that one app was rejected due to storing private information. Can somebody give a reference to an official guideline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you collect any user information and that data is sent to a server then you need to explain to the user what is about to happen and give an option to opt out. This applies, for example, to highscore and leaderboard liets. And even if the information submitted is just a bogus name that the user enters specifically for this purpose. In your app Its not just some random info its Address book info so now you decide what to do hope now you know what to do :)

If your app uses Core Location for the sole purpose of serving ads or user tracking, then your app will be rejected for sure